# JavaScript - error this.first() is not a function

Tags: javascript, this, scopes

I'm just playing around and trying to figure out how the **this** object works and how do I pass scopes context with the **bind** function.
So far I got to this point (check code below), and found out that I can use bind with an object function in order to pass the scope of **myObject** to the object function **run**.

first question:

> why do I need to use this.first() instead of first()?

Because otherwise its still using **second's** context.

```
    myObject = {
    first: function(){ console.log("myObject's first()")},
    second: function(){ 
        function first(){ console.log("second's first()")};
        let run = function(){ this.first()}.bind(this);
        run();

    },
}

myObject.second()
```

Next, I wanted to take it to the next level and I nested another function within **second** (check code).
Second question:

> From the code below i get the error **Error: this.first is not a
>   function**, and whether i invoke **.bind(this)** or not it gives the
>   same error, any clue why does this happen?

```
myObject = {
    first: function(){ console.log("myObject's first()")},
    second: function(){ 
        function first(){ console.log("second's first()")};
        function secondx2(){
            function first(){ console.log("secondx2's first()")};
            let run = function(){ this.first()}
            run();
        }
        secondx2();
    },
}

myObject.second()
```

Comment: `this` and variable scope are pretty much unrelated. `Function#bind` returns a new function that calls its target function with a specific `this` value, but doesn’t affect scope at all, like `call` and `apply`.

Comment: You called `secondx2()` without providing it a `this`. Do `secondx2.call(this);` NB: Consider using arrow functions, the way it uses the *lexical* `this` is probably more suitable for your case.

Comment: @Ryan ya, but why can't i run this.first() i the second snippet?

Comment: @user3676224: Explained by trincot’s comment and the duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using arrows or try to store this in a global variable to access your functions

```js
myObject = {
    first: function(){ console.log("myObject's first()")},
    second: function(){ 
        var scope = this;
        function first(){ console.log("second's first()")};
        function secondx2(){
            function first(){ console.log("secondx2's first()")};
            let run1 = function(){ scope.first()} //myObject's first()

            let run2 = function(){ first()}//secondx2's first()

            run1();
            run2();
        }
        secondx2();
    },
}

myObject.second()
```